# Nested asp.NET ListView

Tags: asp.net, c#-3.0

I have a structure that looks like this:
Strategies  1..n Objectives
Objective 1..n Initiatives

Each are in a different table and linked through foreign keys.

I want to be able to nest my results in a few list view (3 to be exact).

When I try to create a dynamic ID for my nested ListView, the code doesn't compile anymore.

```
  <asp:ListView ID="ObjectivesListView" runat="server">
        <LayoutTemplate>
        <table style="width:100%">
                <tr style="align-content:flex-start">
                    <th>#</th>
                    ...
                </tr>
                <asp:PlaceHolder ID="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </table>
        </LayoutTemplate>
        <ItemTemplate>
        <tr >
          <td onclick='toggleDiv("obj",<%#Eval("ID") %>)'>
              <%# Container.DataItemIndex + 1 %>
          </td>

          ...
        </tr>
            <tr id='obj<%#Eval("ID") %>' class="hide">
                <td colspan="7">Another item
                     <!-- New list view with the initiative for Objective x -->
                        <asp:ListView runat="server" ID="initiativeListView">
                            <LayoutTemplate></LayoutTemplate>
                            <ItemTemplate></ItemTemplate>
                        </asp:ListView>
                    <!-- New list view with the initiative for Objective x -->
                    </td>
        </tr>

        </ItemTemplate>

    </asp:ListView>
```

I have tried to create a dynamic ID for my second listView by doing ID="initiativeListView<%#Eval(ID)%>"> and that causes the error.

I am also running in a sharepoint environment and limited to the ASP classes. I wanted to preload and display it when the user clicks on the row.

Any Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

In your child control instead of Eval(ID) you need to use

```
Eval(Container.Parent, "DataItem.ID")%
```

in first child and

```
Eval(Container.Parent.Parent, "DataItem.ID")%
```

in the second child of your nested controls